# How to add sum value to every row?

Tags: sql-server, sum, duplicates

Below is my table:

```
id  order_number    order_date  order_details
---------------------------------------------
1      222          01-01-2020       44
2      222          02-01-2020       66
3      222          03-01-2020       20
4      223          03-01-2020       33
5      224          04-01-2020       55
6      225          02-01-2020       77
```

I want to have sum(order_details) where order_number = 222

like this table

```
order_date       sum_order_details
----------------------------------
01-01-2020       130
02-01-2020       130
03-01-2020       130
```

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
select  order_number , order_date , sum(order_details) sum_orders from ex
group by order_number
having order_number = 222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* like you're after this is a windowed `SUM`:

```
SELECT order_date,
       SUM(order_details) OVER () AS sum_orders
FROM YourTable
WHERE order_number = 222;
```